# Downloading file using scp from a remote server. But returning error

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, scp

I tried downloading a file from my bluehost account, I'm trying to do it remotely with bash like this

```
 $ scp user@domain.com:/public_html/directory/file.php ~/Desktop/file.php
```

But it returns this response:

```
declare -x CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/jdk/lib/classes.zip"
```

I don't know if this is an error, but nothing has been copied.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `~/.bashrc` file on the remote server is broken. Try to use a standard `~/.bashrc` for your system (for testing) and try again

Comment: what kind of linux distribution is running on the server?

Comment: Ok, understood, you are on shared hosting. I would suggest to write an email to the support. They will help you with this.